How to enable platformcharges using initiatepay PGlink in Easebuzz
currently, I am Generate Payment link using Easebuzz. It works fine.
but I want to enable platform charges in Easebuzz.
enter image description here
They have a demo page which contains platform charges in Details.
But in my interface, i have only Amount to
pay
